# The property of suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology

THe suspension $\Sigma X$ of a topological sapce $X$ is defined as the qutient space $$ \Sigma X=\dfrac{X\times [0,1]}{\sim}$$
Where $(x,t)\sim(y,s)$ if and only if $s=t=0$ or $s=t=1$ or $(x,t)=(y,s)$.
Sow that $\Sigma X$ is simply connected if $X$ is path connected.

I hope to use Van kampen to prove this.In order to do that ,we can find two open covers whose fundamental groups are trivial and so does thier intersection.But I don't know how to find such open covers.

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove isn't true.  Are you sure you've written it correctly?

Comment: Are you sure it's not that $X$ needs to be path connected? Otherwise, $X=S^0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @DanRust I make a mistake.$X$ should be path connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U = (X \times [0,0.6))/{\sim}$ and let $V = (X \times (0.4,1])/{\sim}$. Note that $U$ and $V$ deformation retract onto a space which is homeomorphic to $CX$, the [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)) over $X$, which is always contractible. Now use Van Kampen's theorem to finish the proof (this is where you use path-connected).